# Switch between texts in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was able to replace text on click by the following code:

```
function changetext() {
    document.getElementById("accounts").innerHTML = "Create Account";
}

<span id="accounts" onclick="changetext()">Login</span>
```

This replacing `Login` by `Create Account` when clicked, but does not switch back to `Login` when clicked on `Create Account`. I need to switch between `Login` and `Create Account`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So add an if and check what state the text is in and set the correct text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic check to see what the text is:

```js
function changetext() {
    var div = document.getElementById("accounts");
    var text = div.innerHTML == "Create Account" ? "Login" : "Create Account";
    div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<span id="accounts" onclick="changetext()">Login</span>
```

---

Or no JavaScript at all

```css
input[name="log"] { display : none; }
input[name="log"] + label.a {} 
input[name="log"] + label.a + label.b { display:none } 
input[name="log"]:checked + label.a {display:none} 
input[name="log"]:checked + label.a + label.b { display: inline }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="log" name="log" /><label class="a" for="log">Text 1</label><label class="b" for="log">2 Text</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the innerHTML using if condition and change

```
function changetext() {
   var element =  document.getElementById("accounts");
   element.innerHTML = (element.innerHTML==="Login") ? "Create Account" : "Login";
}

<span id="accounts" onclick="changetext()">Login</span>
```

Comment: He said, that he dont need switch back to login!)

Comment: Please check OP has mentioned that OP wants to revert back the text

Answer (score 1):

When you click the content of your span tag changetext() function is invoked, which changes the content to "Create Account".
So you could do something like this:-

```
function changetext() {
    if(document.getElementById("accounts").innerHTML == "Login"){
    document.getElementById("accounts").innerHTML = "Create Account";
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("accounts").innerHTML = "Login";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to put document.getElementById("accounts") in a variable to make it cleaner